# Making youtube video to autoplay

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, youtube-api

I need help. I have been trying this for days now. I need to integrate a Youtube video to my iPhone application (**without exiting the application**). The thing is that i know how to embed the video. but i need to autorun the video without showing the thumbnail.

My code shows a thumbnail view, and after i click it the video starts to play. But what i need is to play the video automatically (without displaying the thumbnail view first).

I have seen many application that has done this, but i am unable to implement it in my application.

Here's my code, can you tell me what is wrong, and how to fix it.

I have also included the parameter `autoplay` still its not working.

**note**: I have already seen apps that has this feature :)

```
NSString *html = @"<html><head>    <meta name = \"viewport\" content = \"initial-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no, width = 212\"/></head>    <body style=\"background:#F00;margin-top:0px;margin-left:0px\"> <param name=\"movie\" value=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/VO6FQ62Vip4\"></param><param name=\"allowFullScreen\" value=\"true\"></param><param name=\"autoplay\" value=\"1\"></param><embed src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/VO6FQ62Vip4\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" width=\"560\" height=\"315\" allowfullscreen=\"true\" autoplay=1></embed></body></html>";


        [webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com/embed/VO6FQ62Vip4"]];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to find the play button that is inside the UIWebView and send it UIEventTouchUpInside action.

Answer (score 0):

So my html looked like

```
<div class="video-autoplay">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/wqFLcE923fc" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

and I made jQuery code to add the variables that are required to autoplay youtube video so, once user paste the youtube embed code, it right away makes the video autoplay.

```
const iframeVideo = $('.video-autoplay > iframe');
    if (iframeVideo.length !== 0) {
      try {
        let _this = $('.video-autoplay > iframe');
        let video = _this.attr('src');
        let videoId = _this.attr('src').split('/').pop();
        _this.attr(
          'src',
          `${video}?autoplay=1&mute=1&vol=0&loop=1&playlist=${videoId}`
        );
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
      }
    }
```